# Frequent Mysql Connection Refused Issue with Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

My Laravel app is working normally but every now and then I get this error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`
It only happens for few seconds then when I request the rest apis again it works

```
{message: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused", exception: "Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception",…}
exception
: 
"Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDO\\Exception"
file
: 
"/var/www/...../vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDO/Exception.php"
line
: 
18
message
: 
"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused"
```

Comment: no as my issue doesn't happen all the time, I mean the connection is working successfully but sometimes I got this error then after few seconds it works successfully again without any changes from my side

Comment: Looks like the database is being exhausted (too many connections or similar), can you tell us what are you doing to reproduce the error? Else it is going to be imposible to help you

Comment: I just use the system for some time and then the issue happens, the server doesn't have any other load maybe except me using it to enter some data into the system

Comment: Is the database on the same machine as the API? If that is the case, how much RAM does that machine have? If you check right now how much RAM is being used?

Comment: yes both mysql and api are running on the same machine, the machine has 2GB of RAM and currently the RAM used is 1.36 GB

Comment: It is then possible that the machine is running out of memory. This happened to me and MySQL would throw the same error as you are sharing. Check the MySQL logs on `/var/log/` and see if you find any sudden stop or memory issues for mysql